# AJAX stop propagation next calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-events

I am making global interceptor of ajax calls, to track some specific responces and prevent next calls.

The local call is:

```
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "PUT",
        url: url + '/0'
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log('LOCAL: this should not be seen too');
        nextUser();
    });
```

The interceptior is

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        console.log("GLOBAL: start");
    }).ajaxSend(function (e, xhr, opts) {
        console.log("GLOBAL: send");
    }).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, opts) {

        console.log("GLOBAL: error");

    }).ajaxSuccess(function (e, xhr, opts) {
        if (xhr.responseJSON.test) {
            $('#upgradeModal').modal('show');
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

            // change status code
            xhr.abort();
            return false;
        }
        console.log("GLOBAL: this should not be seen");
    }).ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, opts) {
        console.log("GLOBAL: complete");
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
        console.log("GLOBAL: stop");
    });
```

Really I need to thack ajaxSuccess or ajaxComplete but others put here just to test.
The result is

```
GLOBAL: start 
GLOBAL: send 
GLOBAL: complete
GLOBAL: stop
LOCAL: this should not be seen too
```

So this console.log

> "GLOBAL: this should not be seen"

is not shown correct, but I need not to see this

> "LOCAL: this should not be seen too"

also. As you see I tried everything in code like "stopImmediatePropagation" but still nothing. Is is possible to stop propagation of this ajax call?

Comment: Why doesn't a request handle a possible error on its own?

Comment: This is not error basically it is custom string there, could be "xhr.responseJSON.test"